# "Commutative categories"

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let's say that category $\mathcal{C}$ is commutative if the following choices of compositions between two objects $x, y\in \text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ are the same
$ x\overset{f}{\to} y\overset{g}{\to} x\overset{h}{\to} y, \ x\overset{h}{\to} y\overset{g}{\to} x\overset{f}{\to} y$. This property can be stated in the following way: if $f_1\circ ... \circ f_i\circ ...\circ f_j\circ ...\circ f_n$ is a (well-defined) composition of morphsisms with $i<j$ and $f_i, f_j$ having the same domain and codomain, then this composition is equal to $f_1\circ ...\circ f_j\circ ...\circ f_i\circ ...\circ f_n$. That is, we can permute compositions as long as it's well-defined.

This clearly generalizes commutativity from monoids and groups to arbitrary categories. Does this property have a name? Is it useful? Is it studied?

Comment: Which examples do you have in mind?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg So far the only examples that come to mind are categories such that $\text{Hom}(x, y)$ contains at most one element for $x\neq y$ and monoid corresponding to each object is commutative. I don't have any naturally occurring examples of those. But if you think about abelian groups and groups, then groups correspond to some permutations of a set, while abelian groups are in this non-abstract sense harder to find. So I don't think it means that the concept I introduced is downright not useful.

Comment: I don't think that it is fruitful to write down a definition which generalizes some other definition without having any specific example or goal in mind. This also applies to category theory, which aims for generality not just for the sake of generality. Your comment confirms my suspicion that this applies here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The purpose of this question was to learn if something like that already exists and where it's used. And it's certainly fruitful to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the exact definition you provide has not been studied. However, there is another concept that captures the idea of commutativity in categories which may be what you're looking for.

Let us call a category $\mathscr C$ *symmetric* if it is equipped with an [identity-on-objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/identity-on-objects+functor) functor $({-})^\bullet \colon \mathscr C^\circ \to \mathscr C$ from its opposite, which is an [isomorphism of categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_of_categories). This means that, for every morphism $f \colon A \to B$ there is a morphism $f^\bullet \colon B \to A$ such that $(f^\bullet)^\bullet = f$. In many ways this satisfies our intuition of commutativity: given a chain of morphisms $f \circ g \circ h$, we have a chain of morphisms $h^\bullet \circ g^\bullet \circ f^\bullet$ satisfying $(h^\bullet \circ g^\bullet \circ f^\bullet)^\bullet = f \circ g \circ h$. So $\mathscr C$ can be thought of as "commutative up to $({-})^\bullet$".

We could furthermore ask for the symmetric $({-})^\bullet$ to be an *equality* of categories, so that $\mathscr C(A, B) = \mathscr C(B, A)$. If $\mathscr C$ has one object, then this exactly asks for $\mathscr C(*, *)$ to be a commutative monoid, but this is an unnaturally strict property to ask for in category theory.

In fact, symmetric categories have been well studied in the literature, though in recent literature you are more likely to find them called [dagger categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dagger+category), and you will find plenty of examples under that name.